# How to override/extend Odoo 17 Owl JS?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm having trouble extending this class to modify the export dialog and button. I'm able to see the first log item in the console so I know that file is properly declared in the manifest.  But the class I'm trying to extend (ExportDataDialog) is not showing log items.

```html
/** @odoo-module **/
import { ExportDataDialog } from "@web/views/view_dialogs/export_data_dialog";

console.log('Test log to verify JS file is loading.');

class ExtendedExportDataDialog extends ExportDataDialog {
    setup() {
        console.log('Not seeing this log item');
        super.setup(); 
    }

    async onClickExportButton() {
        console.log("Extended export button click handler. Not seeing this log item either.");

        if (super.onClickExportButton) {
            await super.onClickExportButton();
        }
    }

    onAddItemExportList(fieldId) {
        console.log("item added to export list..Not seeing this log item either.");
        this.state.exportList.push(this.knownFields[fieldId]);
        this.enterTemplateEdition();
    }
    onRemoveItemExportList(fieldId) {
        console.log("item removed from export list..Not seeing this log item either.");
        const item = this.state.exportList.findIndex(({ id }) => id === fieldId);
        this.state.exportList.splice(item, 1);
        this.enterTemplateEdition();
    }
}

ExtendedExportDataDialog.components = ExportDataDialog.components;
ExtendedExportDataDialog.props = ExportDataDialog.props;
ExtendedExportDataDialog.template = ExportDataDialog.template;
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code and the official docs and solved it using patch.

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import { ExportDataDialog } from "@web/views/view_dialogs/export_data_dialog";
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";

console.log('Test log to verify JS file is loading.');


patch(ExportDataDialog.prototype, {
    /**
     * @override
    */
    
    async onClickExportButton() {
        console.log("This is the way.");
        if (!this.state.exportList.length) {
            return this.notification.add(_t("Please select fields to save export list..."), {
                type: "danger",
            });
        }

        this.state.disabled = true;
        await this.props.download(
            this.state.exportList,
            this.state.isCompatible,
            this.availableFormats[this.state.selectedFormat].tag
        );
        this.state.disabled = false;
    }
});
```